# Send email through devise is failing using Gmail account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Rails 4.2.1
Devise 3.4.1
```

I inherited an application, that, up until about a year ago, was sending notifications, without a problem. Then it was down for about a year. I am trying to restart it, and was testing a password reset action, but I am not receiving the emails.

ActionMailer (production environment), is set up as follows:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_smtp_server,
    port: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_smtp_port,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I tested the gmail account, and password, and it's all working fine. This is an individual freebie Gmail account, not a paid account.

I noticed that the "Less secure app access" was switched off, so I switched it off, and tried again, but I was not receiving the notification email, even though production log said it was sending email:

```
Sent mail to xxx@xxxxxxxx.net (539.2ms)
```

So, I added the following:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

And when I ran it again, I saw the "Something went wrong" dialog, and now in production log, I have the following:

```
F, [2020-01-29T18:42:39.172134 #16986] FATAL -- : 
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs
):
  app/models/user.rb:38:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try this? https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: @FeifeiXiong That is not an option for me, because this is an individual account, and not a paid account

Comment: My account is an individual account and not paid, I also did this to enable email sending.

Comment: It worked this time. I was logged in to another account, and when I logged out, and I tried the UnlockCaptcha initially, it logged me back into the other account. The UI is very confusing.

Comment: Yep, you should swap your user index in the URL address. accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha is using your first login google user, u can change 0 to another number.

Comment: How do I know which number to use?

Comment: Go to Gmail, and switch to the account you want to use, check the number in URL address

Comment: Yes, i figured it out, but the UI is still pretty bad, at a minimum, it should tell you what account you're on. In any case, this works only for a few minutes to allow my browser to request a password change, but when other users try to request a password change, the app crashes. I asked this in another question on Stackoverflow

Comment: Yea, ugly UI and bad user experience.